# why it is not working to remove if it the same color name?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a problem

My currentColor goes not to null, If I Press a color I set the color to currentColor, if the same color is again pressed then I remove the color (I set currentColor to null). but its not working

```
const ModalProductSizeColor = forwardRef<BottomSheetModal, IModalProductSizeColor>(({ onPress }, ref) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParams>>();

  const [currentColor, setCurrentColor] = useState<ColorsOptions | null>(null);
  const [sizeScreen, setSizeScreen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['25%', 250], []);

  const handleSetCurrentColor = (color: ColorsOptions) => {
    console.log(currentColor + 'current in func');
    currentColor === color ? setCurrentColor(null)  : setCurrentColor(color)
  };

  console.log(currentColor);
  return (
    <BottomSheetModal
      ref={ref}         
      index={1}
      snapPoints={snapPoints}
      handleIndicatorStyle={[s.handleStyle, s.handleColorWhite]}
      backdropComponent={BottomSheetBackdrop}
    >
      <Text style={s.title}>test</Text>

        <Colors
          colors={ColorsData}
          onPress={handleSetCurrentColor}
          onLongPress={(x) => console.log(x)}
          containerStyle={s.containerStyle}
        />
      
      <View style={s.btnContainer}>
        <Pressable style={ButtonStyles.full}>
          <Text style={s.btnText}>Fertig</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </BottomSheetModal>
  )
});
```

In my function when I console.log currentColor its null but outside of the function it is setted , I dont check anything anymore I am very thankful for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Colors` component passes the `color` to your `handleSetCurrentColor`, you could try to set your `currentColor` like this

```js
...
console.log(currentColor + 'current in func');
setCurrentColor(prevCurrentColor => prevCurrentColor === color ? null : color)
...
```

Comment: thanks works, but why I currentColor always undefined in my function ? that doesnt make sense, everytime its null and outside its setted

Comment: It seems like you can't trigger a function with a ternary operator immediately. If you use an normal `if` `else` statement it works just fine